# (the?) day after tomorrow

Tags: phrases

It seems to me that when used as a noun, 'day after tomorrow' is preferred with 'the.'

'The day after tomorrow is the deadline.'

But when used adverbially it is not so-prefaced.'

'I'll see you the day after tomorrow.'

After all, we don't say 'I'll see you the tomorrow' or '...the next year.'

What do you think?

Comment: "I'll see you *the* day after tomorrow."  It looks "so-prefaced" to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: _The day after tomorrow_ is a specific point in time, just like _tomorrow_, _next week_ or _Friday_. As you see, the _the_ is simply part of the whole expression and I cannot think of any situation where you would use _day after tomorrow_ without the article for _day_.

Comment: "On the morrow" is always used with the article. But that's archaic.  It just means tomorrow.  I think the idiom ate our article in common usage and people just haven't gotten around to dropping it off of "the day after" yet.  Tomorrow isn't the idiom here.  "The day after ____" is.  "The day after labor day" etc.

Comment: Ask George Carlin.

Answer (score 1):

"tomorrow" is unique. There is just one tomorrow for a given speaker at a given time.  In that sense it has the status of a name and so does not require an article.  In writing of a more poetic nature we could refer to "a tomorrow" but that doesn't apply in your context.

"the day after" has no identity of its own. It refers to relationship in time.

Comment: If _tomorrow_ is unique, there is only one specific, unique _day after_ it. I am not sure that uniqueness explains the article.

Comment: @oerkelens That wasn't my point. There is no unique date associated with the phrase "the day after". It derives all of its meaning from whatever follows.